# How to get the Html content of multiple div

Tags: jquery, html

Please I want to get the HTML contents of many div with the same id this is my code:

```
<div id="my_div">This is content I</div>
<div id="my_div">This is content J</div>
<div id="my_div">This is content P</div>
<div id="my_div">This is content Z</div>
```

And this is my jQuery code:

```
document.getElementById('my_div').innerHTML;
```

But it only gives me the contents of one div. eg `This is content I`. This is what I really want `This is content IThis is content JThis is content PThis is content Z`. Please how do I run my code?

Comment: You can't give same id to multiple div. Id should be unique. Instead of id you can use class

Comment: either use different id's for each div, or use a className or data-attr for this.

Comment: Bad markup. `The id attribute specifies a unique id for an HTML element (the value must be unique within the HTML document).`

Comment: Also you will have to iterate trough all the `div` elements to get the specific values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add same class to all div: Try this:

```
<div class="my_div">This is content I</div>
<div class="my_div">This is content J</div>
<div class="my_div">This is content P</div>
<div class="my_div">This is content Z</div>

var str ="";
 $(".my_div").each(function() {
    str = str + $(this).html() + " ";
 })
 alert(str)
```

Answer (score 1):

Start with:

```
<div class="my_div">This is content I</div>
<div class="my_div">This is content J</div>
<div class="my_div">This is content P</div>
<div class="my_div">This is content Z</div>
```

Then use a jQuery .each on a selector of .my_div. See answer from Dhara Parmar

```
$(".my_div").each(function( index ) {
    console.log( index + ": " + $( this ).html() );
});
```

Will show you the results and then finally, concatenate in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Change your html to use `class` instead of `id` :

```
<div class="my_div">This is content I</div>
<div class="my_div">This is content J</div>
<div class="my_div">This is content P</div>
<div class="my_div">This is content Z</div>
```

And the loop through its values to get each one of them:

```
function showDivValues(){
    var length = document.getElementsByClassName('my_div').length;

    for(var i = 0; i < length; i++){
         console.log(document.getElementsByClassName('my_div')[i].innerHTML);
    }
}
```